# How to insert rasters to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have rasters (1.4GB) in TIFF format. My question is how to generally import rasters to MySQL?

Comment: my advice is: don't do it. Keep files on the FILEsystem, where they belong. DATAbase is for data.

Comment: Look here why: [File save on File System VS In Database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6809721/684229)

Comment: My question is 'why inport raters to MySQL'?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea, but you could use a BLOB (Binary Large Object) field.

INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (BLOBFIELDNAME) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('/youfile.TIF'));

Max size for a longblob is 4,294,967,296 bytes.